# How to animate the visibility of a constraint?

Tags: animation, constraints, keyframes

How to animate the "Copy location" constraint visibility?

Comment: Set the influence to 0 *or* try to animate the visibility of the constraint.

Comment: but... how to animate the visibility of the constraint?

Comment: place the cursor over the visibility icon and press I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Place the cursor over the 'visibility property'
2. Press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe
3. Go to the next frame, *disable* the visibility and press <kbd>I</kbd> again
4. Go to the next frame, *enable* the visibility and insert a keyframe

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it is to animate the influence. If you want a sudden effect, then poor's way gives the desired result. However, if you would like to have a smoother effect, you could animate the influence factor.
[image]

Insert an keyframe for the influence set to 1 on frame one.
[image]

Scroll to another frame, and and insert another keyframe set to 1

[image]

Go the next frame and set the influence to 0, and insert a keyframe
[image]

And then, go once again to the following frame, and set the influence to 1, and insert a keyframe.

[image]

Comment: Consider creating a gif to avoid too many similar screenshots - http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers